# Using jQuery is it posible to include a file based on screen resolution?

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, media-queries, adsense

A website I am working on uses media queries in the CSS to adjust the layout based on screen size.

This website is utilizing Google Ads, to help monetize.

If I am correct there isn't a responsive ad unit offered by Google AdSense I can use.

My idea was to create two include files (google-300x250.html and google-320x50.html) and include one or the other based on the current screen resolution.

Has anyone else tried implementing something similar? What technologies did you use to get this working?

If I beat someone to a solution I will edit my question/post to include my solution.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "include one or the other"? You could always get the screen resolution using JS in a staging page and then redirecting to one or the other, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will grab the HTML from the specified file and load it into a container:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    if ($(this).width() > 320) {
        $('#my-container').load('google-320x50.html');
    } else {
        $('#my-container').load('google-300x250.html');
    }
});
```

This is if you are using an iframe to show the external pages. All you need to do is update the source of the iframe:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    if ($(this).width() > 320) {
        $('#my-iframe').attr('src', 'google-320x50.html');
    } else {
        $('#my-iframe').attr('src', 'google-300x250.html');
    }
});
```

These chunks of code are using `320px` as the break-point for showing one version or another. Also, if you want to support window resizes as well you can change the code to run on the `window.resize` event rather than the `window.load` event, but you should throttle it so it doesn't run too often.

For example:

```
var timer   = null;
$(window).on('load', function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        if ($(this).width() > 320) {
            $('#my-container').load('google-320x50.html');
        } else {
            $('#my-container').load('google-300x250.html');
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

This will only run once the resize event has finished (or paused for 100ms), meaning you won't create a ton of AJAX requests in the process. You could also setup a flag so you don't run multiple requests at once, the flag can be resolved in the callback function for the `.load()` method.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, that was quick!

Answer (score 0):

Just include both...

use your media queries to show/block the irrelevant one:

```
@media (max-width:500px) {
#largeAd{display:none}
#smallAd{display:block}
 }

@media (min-width:500px) {
#largeAd{display:block}
#smallAd{display:none}
 }
```

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I believe this goes against the TOS. I don't think Google would like me hiding their Ads since impressions are still being served.